# CSS animation text slide / swims inside of input text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a small project related to the file server.
I have created a link return to the file in the input type "url" and next to the file name. The whole thing is responsive using display: flex.

Everything looks good on a computer or tablet, but when use phone or emulate phone on chrome. The link is long and the name has to be truncated to make it look good. I came up with the idea to make the text slide. And it works cool using that code css

```
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0% {text-indent:100%;}
    100% {text-indent: -100%;}
}

.marquee {
  -webkit-animation: marquee 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 0.52, 0.96);
  }
```

However, I would like to get something better, so that the text flows from one edge to the other alternately.
Check out this crafted gif:
https://ibb.co/4TvLpXN

And the problem that happened to me is one more and probably more important>>
On small screens, responsive mode reduces the input field and reduces "text overflow" more.
Then starts the slide from the starting point.

Web can see here https://tracker.tryhackx.org/PONDO/

Also, I would like the slide effect to only work when it is not possible to see the whole thing. So how to check if the text fits into the input? And how to check in span if "text overflow" has cut the text?

[CSS animation inside of input text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236105/css-animation-inside-of-input-text)

Comment: I hope this like suitable for you..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068754/css-animate-text-from-left-to-right-in-div-container-with-overflow-hidden

Comment: Yeah it "alternate" is that what I search but, how to set 100% and -100% properly because when the screen scales the effect breaks completely? Look that use chrome dev tool or mobile
https://tracker.tryhackx.org/PONDOv3/